# Make some kind of Event System in ruby

Tags: ruby, events, alias

I have this kind of code:

```
module EventSystem
  @@events = {
    :on_minute_change = [],
    :on_hour_change = []
  }

  def self.register_action(event, action)
    @@events[event].push(action)
  end

  def self.notify_event(event)
    @@events[event].each do |action|
      Actions.send(action)
    end
  end
end

module Actions
  def self.make_something
    p "something is happening"
  end

  def self.make_something_else
    p "something else is happening"
  end
end

EventSystem.register_action(:on_minute_change, :make_something)
EventSystem.register_action(:on_minute_change, :make_something_else)
EventSystem.register_action(:on_hour_change, :make_something)

class Own_Time
  def next_minute
    # minute += 1
    EventSystem.notify_event(:on_minute_change)
  end

  def next_hour
    # hour += 1
    EventSystem.notify_event(:on_hour_change)
  end
end

@own_time = Own_Time.new

@own_time.next_minute
@own_time.next_minute
@own_time.next_hour
```

OUTPUT:

```
"something is happening"
"something else is happening"

"something is happening"
"something else is happening"

"something is happening"
```

The reason for all of this is, that I want to have a base code and add new optional addons to 
the base to keep it modular and changeable. I could also for example alias the next_minute method instead of having an event which will call all registered methods. But because I will have many addons this would mean that I will have to use many aliases so I thought of a simpler way.

Now Im wondering if my approach is ok or if there are some flaws and problems with my code.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you're trying to recreate an already very well understood design pattern, the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). The Ruby Standard Library already has a module that will help you accomplish this. It is documented [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/observer/rdoc/Observable.html). I've given you an example below, but the example in the documentation is more thorough. Disclaimer: it's getting late, so I apologize if I've completely misunderstood your question.

```
class Timer
  include Observable

  def run
    # TODO: add code to check time here
    # TODO: check whether minute or hours have changed here

    # call this when minute is changed
    change 

    # notify the objects observing the timer and call
    # the method that you want to trigger
    # NOTE: you can pass in args here that might need
    # to be passed into the method on the receiving
    # observer
    notify_observers(args)
  end
end

class ExampleMaker
  def make_something(args)
    # do something with args
  end
end

timer = Timer.new
maker = ExampleMaker.new
timer.add_observer(maker, :make_something)
```

Comment: I realized it may not be completely clear from my example, but you'll need to insert your own logic for notifying certain observers when the hour changes versus when just the minute changes. I'm just trying to point you in the right direction, not write your code for you.

Comment: No sweat. If you have any additional questions I'd be happy to help clarify my answer.

Comment: Yeah it was a good direction, I dont use the default observable module, but with some changes made to the source.

Comment: Wonderful. Yeah, you could certainly implement the pattern yourself. Glad it helped.